# Forcing a selected HTML form option on an third-party page?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, iframe

I'm working with a third-party salon booking "plugin" (really just an iframe that loads their own booking tool... Vagaro is the name of it if anyone's had experience with it), and I want to be able to load it in the iframe with certain options already selected in their drop-down forms.

However, Vagaro itself doesn't have this capability built in to its code, so it's not as simple as just passing some parameters/variables through the URL. I've tried that a few different ways, (...?service=womenshaircut&serviceprovider=anne, for a simplistic example) and it's just not something that their tool is built to do.

Is there any sort of script to force these forms to select options of my choosing when loading their page into an iframe on my own page?

Sorry I can't include any example code. Since their page is obviously not my own work, I probably shouldn't copy/paste any of it here. But hopefully the idea explained is simple enough that you guys might understand it.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read the Vagaro Terms of Service / User Agreement?  `https://www.vagaro.com/User-agreement`   What exactly what are you trying to do?  Note: it might make more sense to have them update their API to accommodate your usage, perhaps there is $$ for them in that...  If it made good business sense, you could volunteer to write the API updated code, per their approval process.

Comment: So the "what exactly" part is actually quite simple. I'm building a site for a salon, where each stylist (service provider) has a short bio visible. I want a link under each stylist that says "Book appt with this stylist," which would take you to the iframed Vagaro tool in a state where that stylist is already selected from the 'Service Provider' dropdown. As it is now, the user must manually select their chosen stylist from Vagaro's dropdown. Same goes for the salon's Service Menu, with links to Vagaro's tool pre-selected for each given Service Menu item.

Comment: From what I can tell, this wouldn't be violating any of their user agreement, unless someone was getting really, really picky about it. The whole iframe aspect is part of their own Wordpress plugin, so even though it says a user can't "frame" their site, it's specifically how they integrate it on the site.

This is actually a popular request on Vagaro's support site, and plenty of little developers like me are kinda frustrated that they don't include such simple functionality into their tool. I just hoped there was SOME way around it, but I'm not quite qualified to figure it out myself!

Comment: Awesome.  Volunteer to Vagaro that you will update their API tools to be friendly to others that want to use their site in this manner. Sell the concept to Vagaro as the right thing to do. Tell them why letting their users help define who they are (open source concept) is such a good thing for them. Create a straight up API, using Php on their server.  Do it right, document it.  Output to JSON or whatever.  Should take two or three days, max.  In the alternative you could screen scrape their site, create your own, but that is definitely a violation of their terms of service.

Comment: Do this initial API for free (minimum viable product to get the stuff you need.)  Tell them if updates are required later, price is $$/ hour.  Make them successful.  Everybody wins.  Call them now.  Post your offer on social media, that often gets great results.